# A rectangular room has dimensions 3x4x5, what is the shortest distance moving along the walls from one corner to its diametrically opposite corner?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Let us call the starting point $A$ and the end point $B$, there also must be some point along a vertex or edge that the path crosses over, let us call that point $P.$ From this it seems like the problem asks for the lowest value of $AP+PB$.

Now I was pretty stuck on how to represent this as a function, but I settled by deciding to optimize each of six cases. Each case would consist of finding the minimum of some function $f(x)=\sqrt{s^2+x^2}+\sqrt{s_2^2+(s_3-x)^2}$. Where $s$ is the edge which can form a triangle with $AP$, $x$ is the length of the other leg of the triangle formed by $AP$, $s$, and $x$, $s_2$ is the edge not along the face on which $AP$ lies, and $s_3$ is the other edge on the face on which $AP$ lies. Again, I believe that there are six different cases where this can be applied.

However, after finding the minimum of $f(x)=\sqrt{9+x^2}+\sqrt{25+(4-x)^2}$ and finding it to be roughly $8.9$, I decided to check the back of the book I am following to see if I was anywhere on the right track. I found the answer given to be $9.4$, which clearly shows that I have done something terribly wrong.

Also, sorry if this is a bit hard to read, I'm not super familiar with formal notation for this kind of thing, and MS paint was being real annoying today.

Comment: (Nice details added.) Both answers are numerically wrong. The correct answer is $\sqrt{5^2+7^2} \approx 8.6$. You have the right idea, but need to analyze each case. You only listed 1 case where $s= 3, s_2 = 5, s_3 = 4$. Their answer is $ \sqrt{3^2+9^2}$, and your answer is $\sqrt{4^2 + 8^2}$,  both of which use the incorrect $ s_3$. (They used $s_3 = 3$, you used $s_3 = 4$, the correct answer uses $s_3 = 5$.)

Comment: Yes, I understand this, and I didn't think that my answer was correct as I didn't check all cases. I was more confused about whether my method was incorrect in some way, so thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: The key is to note that the shortest distance is on a straight line if you open up the walls and lay them flat.

Comment: Now you have choice of $3$ different straight lines depending on how you place them in $2D$.

Comment: Your problem seems to be very close to, but not exactly the same as the [spider and the fly problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_spider_and_the_fly_problem).  Although I could be mistaken, I suspect that the approach used in that problem will work in your problem.  Also, you could google on : "spider and the fly problem" to find other related articles.

Comment: @user2661923 indeed it is similar. I also think the path to be followed in this problem is easier to visualize than in the spider and the fly problem.

Comment: The basic problem is the specification of the dimension of room, $3\times 4 \times 5$, is ambiguous. If I interpret it literally, it means a room with width $3$, length $4$ and height $5$. In this case, the minimum is $\sqrt{5^2+(3+4)^2} \sim 8.6$. If it means a room with height $3$, then the minimum becomes $\sqrt{3^2+(5+4)^2} \sim 9.4$.

Comment: @achillehui I was struggling to see the problem but finally I noticed "moving along the walls".  Are you interpreting that as not allowing use of the floor?

Comment: @badjohn yup. otherwise, I fail to see the purpose of the phrase "moving along the walls".

Comment: @achillehui I read a little too quickly and interpreted it as staying on a surface rather than flying through the air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments don't allow graphics, we post this hint.

[image]